# How can I resize pictures changing the aspect ratio?

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing, mogrify

Currently running Ubuntu 15.04. I am trying to resize a set of photos where the original size of each is 3906*2602.

Whether I try with darktable or mogrify specifying 1920*1080 I end up with 1621*1080.

For mogrify, I used the following specifications:

```
mogrify -path resized -quality 95 -resize 1920x1080 -strip '*.jpg'
```

There is obviously something I didn't get about picture resizing, but couldn't find any hint anywhere.

Would anyone know why it gets resized to 1621 instead of 1920?

Comment: Your specified dimensions require the aspect ratio to change: does this help: [Resize image with mogrify without keeping aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438898/resize-image-with-mogrify-without-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Comment: `convert`  from the imagemagick package has never failed me yet. As for the ratio thing, its probably trying to maintain a ratio. perhaps there is an option to ignore ratio.  morgify isnt something I use.

Comment: in order to ignore the aspect ratio of the original image you should specify `1920x1080!`

Answer (score 3):

As per Adonis' comment, the exclamation mark, `!` forces mogrify to ignore the aspect ratio of the original image. so using `1920x1080!` in the size parameter did the trick.